# How do I access a ServiceStack service over a network?

Tags: servicestack

Preemptive apologies for this question as I know it should be extremely easy but I'm brand new to ServiceStack and didn't find quite what I was looking for perusing the [ServiceStack wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki). Generally my question is: how do I access a ServiceStack service over a network?

Following some tutorials, I've created a console application that creates a new ServiceStack client using the following syntax:

```
var client = new ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:51721");
var response = client.Post<FlightResponse>("/flights",new FlightRequest{ tfsUriString="http://10.0.1.8:8080/tfs/"});
```

I'm able to create and receive DTO's and it's all good and well but now I want to run console application on another computer and run the service on another computer. I tried popping in the URI of the computer that is hosting the service but I get a WebServiceException -- Bad Request when I do so.

I thought maybe if I played around with my Web.Config settings and modified the system.webServer config I could get it to work but I still just get WebServiceExceptions when I do so.

Can anyone shed light on this? How do I consume a service hosted on another computer? [MSDN Creating Cross Platform Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342871.aspx) was a helpful read but it still uses the same localhost approach. Is it even possible to connect to a service running on another hosts computer?(surely?....)

**Edit:** Added a link to my code on github if it helps! Thanks again [Service Stack Example](https://github.com/uvrd/ServiceStack_examples-master--1-/tree/master/ServiceStack_examples-master)

Comment: Without seeing you server code, you should also check that the request isn't being blocked by the firewall on either client or server.

Comment: Went ahead and added a link to my github if you have the time to view it I know I would be immensely grateful, I checked my firewalls, turned them on and off, and so far didn't have any luck. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You would access ServiceStack services the same way, although it's unusual that you would also need to add the route for ServiceStack Services as it automatically uses the Route defined on the Request DTO also it's better to declare the response type on the Request DTO as well so it doesn't need to be on every call site, so it should something like:

```
[Route("/flights")]
public class GetFlights : IReturn<FlightResponse>
{
    public string tfsUriString { get; set; }
}

var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:51721");
var response = client.Post(new GetFlights {
    tfsUriString = "http://10.0.1.8:8080/tfs/" 
});
```

If you're getting a Bad Request, it's usually due to sending a malformed request, e.g. Validation error. In these cases have a look at the error messages that's on the `WebServiceException`, i.e. you can print the error response with:

```
webEx.ResponseStatus.PrintDump();
```

Also having a look at the raw HTTP Request and Response Headers would also provide a lot of insight on what's wrong with the request.